# Android : How to write into internal memory

Tags: android, io

I made this code to write on a sdcard, now how can I transform it to write into the internal memory ?

```
//private String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/liste.txt"; Path used to write on sdcard

try{
   File file = new File(path);

   BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
   bw.write("something");
    bw.flush();
    bw.close();
catch(Exception e) {...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android each application has its own folder under `/data/data/package/`

this dir is only accessable by your app and the root **if the device is rooted**

to access this dir and read/write to it, you can use:

```
getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(name, mode);
```

and

```
getApplicationContext().openFileInput(name);
```

more about this here : [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: Can I access to the root with getApplicationContext() if my device is not rooted ?

Comment: No you can't, if your device is rooted you can use process builder to do root tasks

Comment: it works though ! FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("samplefile.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);         
         osw.write("something");

But I don't know where is it written

Comment: Yes it works and it is written to /data/data/yourpackage/files directory

Answer (score 0):

USe this code:

```
FileOutputStream fos;
    fos = context.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


    fos.write(data.getBytes()); //write to application top level directory for immediate sending 
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
File file = new File("/data/data/com.example.packagename/files/");

BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));
bw.write("something");
bw.flush();
bw.close();
catch(Exception e) {...}
```

or

```
//To read file from internal phone memory
//get your application context:
Context context = getApplicationContext(); 

filePath = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
File file = new File(filePath);
```